# Calling a parameterized stored procedure using WCF and LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, wcf, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, silverlight-5.0

How can I call a parameterized stored procedure `usp_Get_Products` from my `WCF` service? I have tried calling it without any parameters it works fine but I don't know how to pass a `textbox` value as a parameter from my `About.xaml.cs` file.

**Service.svc.cs file**

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
  ProductDataClassDataContext db = new ProductDataClassDataContext();
  var products = db.usp_Get_Products();
  return products.ToList();
}
```

**Views/About.xaml.cs file**

```
private void OnSearchProductClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ServiceReference1.Service1Client webService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
  webService.GetProductsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProductsCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetProductsCompleted);
  webService.GetProductsAsync();
  txtblcName.Text = txtName.Text;   //Send this as parameter to usp_Get_Products
}

public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ProductGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result; //Binding Datagrid 
}
```

How can I send `txtName.Text` from my xaml.cs file as parameter when calling the stored procedure? I know I'm missing some concepts, I'm new to WCF plus I have never worked on silverlight..

Comment: Presumably when you added the procedure to linq-to-sql it had no parameters - so just remove it, and add the new version with the parameter.

Comment: Done that but my question remains the same i.e how will i send the `txtName` value as parameter when im calling the stored procedure. In above code Im simply calling the sp without passing any parameter. Actually I dont know how to pass it

Comment: You would pass it in the call - `var products = db.usp_Get_Products(name);`

Comment: See [How to: Use Stored Procedures that Take Parameters (LINQ to SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399357%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: txtName.Text is in the `About.xaml.cs` file whereas Im calling `var products = db.usp_Get_Products(name)` in the `Service.svc.cs` file. So I need to know how to pass the value from about.xaml.cs to service.svc.cs

Comment: I know how to call SPs using LINQ to SQL its just the calling of service. I need to pass the textbox value when calling `public List<Product> GetProducts()` but I have no idea how am I going to call it from my xaml.cs file

Comment: Sounds like you just add a parameter to the service method, ie `public List<Product> GetProducts(string name)`

Comment: Tried but tell me how will this method(`GetProducts(name)`) get the value of textbox when the service will be called? This method gets call After the `webService.GetProductsAsync();` line but I have no way of sending txtName.Text to `GetProducts(name)`

Comment: @stuartd you tell me how can I send `txtName.Text` as parameter to the method `public List<Product> GetProducts(string name)` .This is where im stuck.I dont know how to pass a textbox's value to a method called by the service. If I would have been calling it from my xaml.cs file i would simply do GetProducts(txtName.text) but problem is I cant call it like this, its called automatically via service

Comment: All you have to do is pass the parameter with the call, i.e. `webService.GetProductsAsync(txtName.Text);`

Comment: Phew! It solved my problem finally :D

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the stored procedure accepts parameters?
Also can you please post your ProductDataClassDataContext.
Ideally you should modify your service contract to accept the parameters,
in case you don't wanna do it
you can do a filter on the products list like

```
    var products = await webService.GetProductsAsync();
    var filteredProduct = products.Where(item=> item.Name == txtName.Text);
```

Comment: I can't filter rows, I am bound to use an SP. Secondly, my problem is I dont know how to send `txtName.Text` from my xaml.cs to the calling procedure. I want to pass it as parameter

Comment: sure, you can modify your service contract that accepts the name as parameter